# Execute an elevated command in wix

Tags: wix

My goal is to create an MSI Package which executes an external installer or script, and nothing else, and waits for it to end.
I don't need the MSI to do anything else yet.

So my problem is that CMD doesn't get executed with elevated privileges.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<Package Comments='test_exec' Description='test_exec' InstallerVersion='200' Languages='1033' Manufacturer='manufacturer' Platform='x86' InstallPrivileges='elevated' AdminImage='yes' InstallScope='perMachine' />

<Property Id='CMDEXE'>cmd.exe</Property>
<CustomAction Id='LaunchFile' Property='CMDEXE' ExeCommand='cmd' Return='ignore' />
<CustomAction Id='LaunchFile2' Property='CMDEXE' ExeCommand='cmd' Return='ignore' Impersonate='no' Execute='deferred'/>
<!--<Property Id='CMDEXE'>PathTo_PsExec.exe</Property>
<CustomAction Id='LaunchFile' Property='CMDEXE' ExeCommand='-u domain\user -p passw0rd -accepteula cmd /c &quot;whoami /user &amp; pause&quot;' Return='ignore' />-->

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='LaunchFile' Before='InstallInitialize'></Custom>
    <Custom Action='LaunchFile2' After='InstallInitialize'></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to launch 2 CMDs

- One Before "InstallInitialize" without "deferred"
- One After "InstallInitialize" with "deferred", trying to elevate it

Unfortunately the second one doesn't get executed at all!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "external installer" do you mean external MSI? It is impossible to install a MSI while another MSI is already installing.

Comment: No, just a EXE installer. I have to use an MSI because I want to deploy it through GPO.